# What is this extra item that came with my travel bag?

Tags: luggage, identify-this

I've bought a travel bag and there is a piece that came with it that I'm having hard time figuring out what it is used for. Here is the picture:

[image]
[image]

Any idea what it's used for?

Comment: It's hard to get a sense of how big it is. Maybe you could retake the pic with something else next to it to serve as a size comparison?

Comment: I love that it's labelled "guess". Very appropriate.

Comment: Could you also indicate the model of the travel bag? That might help.

Comment: Does some other part fit in that slot (i.e. a suit-hanger) it looks like it's meant to keep something upright (or in some direction) inside one of the compartments. Alternatively, since it's branded, could just be a fancy label ... or something mistakenly put in the wrong bag.

Comment: The size of this is about the size of average hand. And also left side is open (like you can create circle and it can stand on it's own... will post another picture tomorrow). I couldn't find this exact model, the closest look is the one of [Guess Tote Travel bag](http://www.motivators.com/images/products/Promotional-GuessSignatureTravelCompuTote-92320_primary.jpg) but this one is different (doesn't have compartments for laptop, etc).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@Michael and @tohecz are close... but not quite there.

It's not actually a luggage tag... rather it is a *protector* for your luggage tag.

It works like [this one](http://www.leatherology.com/catalog/product/view/id/1743/s/deluxe-luggage-tag-green-leather-dark-lime/category/16/):

[image]

However the rounded shape is intended specifically for the luggage tag that comes on some Guess luggage, such as the one shown [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IJDWSMS):

[image]

I suspect your bag came with a similarly shaped luggage tag.

The long slit allows you to reveal the luggage tag for reading, then easily slides back in place.

Why a luggage tag protector is important is beyond me.

But I believe that's what your mystery item is.

Comment: This is my new answer/best guess after over an hour doing Google Image searches. I've spent enough time now... if this isn't right, good luck :)

Comment: *Why a luggage tag protector is important is beyond me.* Some people are concerned that attaching your address to a suitcase is like attaching it to a big sign that reads, "Here's a house that will be vacant for the next two weeks!" You'll notice that both your examples, as well as the one from the OP, discourage casual reading of the label whilst still enabling it to be opened and read if the bag is lost.

Answer (score 5):

I guess that you can put a label with your personal information there, so that the finder knows who the bag belongs to in case the bag is lost.

Answer (score 4):

I would agree with what Michael says: it's for your personal badge. Typical usage is that you put inside a heavy-paper card with your name and home address. Typically, you put the name there in such a way that it's visible when the paper is inside (so that you can identify your luggage), and you put your home address in such a way that it's covered (so that nobody can get it easily, but still the luggage can be shipped to you if you lose it).

However, I am yet a bit dubious because these things are usually attached to the luggage quite firmly.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is a credit card holder, wallet.  The slot is there to make it easy to push the card(s) out of the wallet.

I found an example of something [somewhat similar](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005F5JNG2) that might help confirm my guess.

The main thing that makes me unsure of my guess is the rounded shape... I would expect a credit card wallet to have square corners to hold the cards snug.

Comment: I tend to think you might be right, the label/address holder thing just doesn't seem right for the size shape and the fact there's no way to attach it. Depends on the actual size I guess.

Comment: @SpaceDog: I feel like I came across one of those a few months ago while researching small wallets for travel. But I now can't find any image or confirmation...  Maybe I dreamed it.